# For every element $E$ of a sigma algebra is there a Borel set $B$ such that $E = f^{-1}(B)$ where $f$ is a $S$-measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working through Chapter 2 of Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis. At one point I wondered if $(X,\mathcal{S})$ a measurable space, $f: X\to \mathbb R$ a $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function, and $E\in \mathcal{S}$, then $\exists$ a Borel subset $B \subset \mathbb R$ such that $E = f^{-1}(B)$.

I couldn't find the answer in the text (yet) or in the exercises. But I believe the statement is true, and my (attempted) proof is below. Is it correct?

**Proof:**

I'll do a proof by contradiction, a contrapositive proof can be done along similar lines.

So suppose $E\in \mathcal{S}$ and $\forall B \subset \mathbb R$ Borel subsets $E \neq f^{-1}(B)$. In particular this implies that
$$
f^{-1}(\mathbb R \backslash B) = f^{-1}(\mathbb R) \backslash f^{-1}( B) = X \backslash f^{-1}( B) \neq X \backslash E
$$

Thus
$$
X = f^{-1}(\mathbb R) = f^{-1}(B \cup \mathbb R \backslash B) = f^{-1}(B) \cup f^{-1}(\mathbb R \backslash B) \neq E \cup X \backslash E
$$
which is a contradiction since for *any* $E \in \mathcal S$ one must have $X = E \cup X \backslash E$.

Comment: If $A\neq C$ and $B\neq D$, does that mean that $A\cup B\neq C\cup D$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No it doesn't, you're right. So I suppose the statement does not hold. I am wondering though if it can hold in certain circumstances, will think about it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final inequality is wrong. You are claiming that because $E\neq f^{-1}(B)$ and $X\setminus E\neq f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus B)$, then it follows that
$$E\cup (X\setminus E)\neq f^{-1}(B)\cup f^{-1}(X\setminus E),$$
and that claim does not follow. It's like saying that since $1\neq 3$ and $4\neq 2$, then $1+4\neq 3+2$.

As to your question, take $X$ to be the reals with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, take $E$ to be any measurable non-borel set and $f$ to be the identity function.

Comment: Yes, I realized the stupid mistake quite soon after I posted and your comment came in. Thank you for the clarifying example.